# Unable to scrape content using html dom parser from a particular website

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have been trying to scrape contents from websites and have been successful with some sites. But my code fails to scrape content from flipkart.com. I use HTML DOM PARSER and this is my code..

```
<?php
include ('simple_html_dom.php');
$scrape_url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-f309-2-tb-external-hard-disk-drive/p/itmehwha6zkhkgfw';
$html = file_get_html($scrape_url);
foreach($html->find('h1._3eAQiD') as $title_s)
echo $title_s->plaintext;
foreach($html->find('div.hGSR34') as $ratings_s)
echo $ratings_s->plaintext;
?>
```

This code is giving empty result. Can someone let me know what the problem is? Is there any other way to scrape contents from this site?

Comment: It may be choking on the content. Or you may expect some js-loaded content to be there. If you can narrow that down it will help us.

Comment: I think the content is js-loaded. Is there any way to scrap contents with php?

Comment: You can [run it through phantomjs](https://phantomjscloud.com/) first. There's also some php selenium library if you want to get crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
get_content_by_class(curl('https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-f309-2-tb-external-hard-disk-drive/p/itmehwha6zkhkgfw'), "hGSR34");

function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
    $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
    curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL
    return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
}

function get_content_by_class($html, $container_class_name) {

    //preg_match_all('/<div class="' . $container_class_name .'">(.*?)<\/div>/s', $html, $matches);
    preg_match_all('#<\s*?div class="'. $container_class_name . '\b[^>]*>(.*?)</div\b[^>]*>#s', $html, $matches);

    // 

    foreach($matches as $match){
        $match1 = str_replace('<','&lt',$match);
        $match2 = str_replace('>','&gt',$match1);
        print_r($match2);
    }  

    if (empty($matches)){
        echo 'no matches found';
        echo '</br>';
    }
    //return $matches;

}
```

Comment: function curl grabs the html from the page, and returns it, get content function gets the html of the content by class